# Backbone.View.extend - events hash

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm going through a tutorial which advises that events can be captured via a view as follows:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: $('#element'),
   events: {},
   render: function(){}
});
```

There doesn't seem to be any documentation associated with this events object. Has it been deprecated or is it obsolete? Or am I just looking in the wrong place: http://backbonejs.org/

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents

Comment: spot on niko. add it as an answer and I'll plus one you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [View.delegateEvents](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents)

> **delegateEvents** delegateEvents([events])
>   Uses jQuery's `on` function to
>   provide declarative callbacks for DOM events within a view. If an
>   events hash is not passed directly, uses `this.events` as the source.
>   Events are written in the format `{"event selector": "callback"}`. The
>   callback may be either the name of a method on the view, or a direct
>   function body. Omitting the selector causes the event to be bound to
>   the view's root element (`this.el`). By default, `delegateEvents` is
>   called within the View's constructor for you, so if you have a simple
>   events hash, all of your DOM events will always already be connected,
>   and you will never have to call this function yourself.
>
> The events property may also be defined as a function that returns an
>   events hash, to make it easier to programmatically define your events,
>   as well as inherit them from parent views.
>
> Using `delegateEvents` provides a number of advantages over manually
>   using jQuery to bind events to child elements during render. All
>   attached callbacks are bound to the view before being handed off to
>   jQuery, so when the callbacks are invoked, this continues to refer to
>   the view object. When `delegateEvents` is run again, perhaps with a
>   different events hash, all callbacks are removed and delegated afresh
>   — useful for views which need to behave differently when in different
>   modes.